# What does "Group" generalize?

Tags: group-theory

In linear algebra, I've learned that the concept of "vector space" is nothing more than the linear space's abstract generalization.
And thanks to this, I've never forgotten the axioms for the vector spaces.

Although the axioms (or the definition) of ["group"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) in abstract algebra are much more straightforward, I can't figure out what a concept of group generalizes.
It seems the concept of group generalizes the coordinate transformation (in an active sense, or just operation), but I am not sure of it.
Could somebody please elaborate on this?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Group is a concept to describe the symmetric properties of the system under study. The most important yields of the Group theory are class and irreducible representations. Each irreducible representation denotes a special type of symmetry state.

Comment: What do you mean by "linear space"? Groups are abstract generalisations of sets of [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), and they are usually taught as such in a first course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups generalize a lot of things actually, because their definition is really easy and only imposes a few "loose" conditions:

- existence of an identity element (in an additive group, it would be $0$, in a multiplicative group, $1$, ...)
- every element has an inverse (for example, for $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with addition, this means that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can find some $-x$ element)
- the operation is associative (which is a very natural property for most operations so it doesn't hurt)

The reason groups are so useful is because we noticed many spaces, when endowed with some operation, behave in much the same way. Here are a few examples of groups:

- $\mathbb{R}$ with addition
- $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ with multiplication
- $O_n$, the group of orthogonal matrices of size $n$. It gets really useful in physics, when you want to talk about angular momentum for example (because orthogonal matrices are basically rotations + reflections). And the closely related $SU_n$, used in quantum mechanics.
- $GL_n$ (group of invertible matrices), $SL_n$ (group of matrices with determinant $1$),...

All of those are infinite groups, and they look very different from each other at first, but since they all have a group structure, we can treat them using group theory tools and theorems (which are often very powerful, and there is a lot of material on the subject).

Intuitively, it's not as straightforward to see it as a generalization of something "concrete" (like a vector space is the generalization of our usual space), because groups can come in so many different forms. The way I see it is that at some point, we started thinking "ok, this structure comes up so often in maths that we'll give it a name, and start treating all of those spaces the same".

And while all the groups mentioned above are infinite, there are plenty of finite groups, which are just as useful:

- $D_{2n}$, which you can see as the symmetry group of an $n-$gon (consisting of rotations and reflections, much in the same way as $O_n$ does. But $D_{2n}$ only contains symmetries of the $n-$gon, instead of symmetries of the whole space)
- $S_n$, the symmetry group of $n$ elements (*ie* the set of permutations of the numbers $1,...n$, endowed with composition)

etc...

The reason it's so useful is, say you come up with a whole new space which you've never seen in your life. Well, if you manage to find an operation on it which makes it a group, then that tells you a great deal of things about your space without you having to do anything.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite disappointing to notice that a group does not generalize something "physically concrete," even though it is so often used in physics. And to whom it may concern, it seems my question was quite misleading; what I wanted to know was the "physical" motivation of introducing the concept of a group, not the definition of it. This is the reason why I wrote this question in physics stackexchange rather than math stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, question got moved, which is kinda sad :/. I'm sorry I couldn't offer a more "physical" explanation, but historically, I think groups were introduced in maths way before they were in physics.  I guess their massive use in physics now is due to the how useful they are to treat symmetries.

Answer (score 0):

Groups don't "generalise" but "abstract" the notion of a symmetry group. One of the simplest example of one, given your understanding of vector spaces, is the additive group of a vector space which is the group of translations.

Comment: Or simpler still, groups generalize addition of numbers.

Comment: @J.G.: There's an even simpler example, the multiplicative group over {+1,-1}, or geometrically, the reflection of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to groups, it would be easier, actually, to start with **semigroups.** A *semigroup* is like a group, but you have only one axiom: associativity.

A semigroup generalizes the idea of a **compositionally-closed set of functions** - that is, functions mapping some domain set into itself, such that if we compose any two functions from the set, that composite is also in the set. Function composition is associative, so any such collection of functions is a semigroup under composition. It is also possible to prove the converse: that there exists a domain set and set of self-functions on that set which have the same structure as any given semigroup.

Now if we require the functions to be bijective, i.e. *invertible* self-maps, then that generalizes to what is known as a **quasigroup**.

Finally, a **group** is what happens when we include all inverses of the invertible maps into the quasigroup. Every group corresponds to a set of bijective self-maps, closed under both composition and inversion, on some domain. For example, the cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_n$ correspond to cyclic permutations of a set of $n$ elements (think of the "rotate" operations that, say, turn "hello" into "lohel" or "llohe".), or if you want a different domain, plane rotations by $\frac{\tau}{n}\ \mathrm{rad}$.